# run multiple solr instance in single server

Tags: php, apache, solr

We are using apache-solr for search.Previously solr is running in production environment.Is it possible to setup another solr instance in same server for another db.Currently the solr is running in 8983 port.If possible,please help in how to configure with my new application.

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider to create new cores for the other DB and to increase the resources given to the single instance?

Comment: @cheffe Yes other db for my new application

Answer (score 8):

Yes, by changing the port no, you can run many instances in a single machine. But it may create a heavy load on your machine, when you'll be having a huge no of indexing and querying for the instances. For production environment, it's better to have single instance in a machine.

To start a separate instance, follow the steps.

1. Take another copy of example folder.
2. While starting the new instance (Say port new no is 4983) use the following command.

> java **-Djetty.port=4983** -jar start.jar

Comment: Already i am having example folder for my old application which is in production.SO,it means that i need to make a copy of same example folder and rename that.I need to place that inside the solr folder.Is it right?What are the files i need to change after doing this.Can you please answer it slight brief.

Comment: Are you using the "example" folder itself provided in the Solr package for production environment? Then copy it with different name. Delete the "data" folder inside solr/collection1/ path as it contains all the previously indexed files. I hope you won't need them as you already have a copy. Modify your schema.xml as per your current requirement. Now you are good to go with the new instance.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for running Solr is to use Solr-Undertow which is a high performance with small footprint server for running Solr.  It is easy to use on local machines for development and also production.  It supports simple config files for running instances with different data directories, ports and more.

(note, I am the author of Solr-Undertow)

Link here:  https://github.com/bremeld/solr-undertow with releases under the "Releases" tab.

Comment: Great!, I will try this some time later. Will comment you if i need any help.